# Why does Jest snapshot show uglified component name instead of exported name

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, jestjs

I've got a (private) npm module that exports several React components. The module is bundled by Webpack and in the generated bundle a reference to one of the components (say `Warning`) looks like this:

```js
t.d(n,"Warning",function(){return ge})
```

Then I've got a React project importing this module:

```js
import { Warning } from 'my-custom-module';

...

render() {
    return (
        <Warning>Lorem ipsum</Warning>
   );
}
```

This all works OK, but when I create a Jest snapshot of the component above, I expect the snapshot to look like

```
<Warning>Lorem ipsum</Warning>
```

but it looks like:

```
<ge>Lorem ipsum</ge>
```

For some reason Jest takes the minified identifier instead of the exported name of the component. How can I see the component name in the Jest snapshot? I'm unsure if I do need to adjust my Webpack config or the Jest setup...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring the uglified version of the 'my-custom-module' it will try to render to the uglified names. However, I assume what you actually you need is to shallowly render your component.

> You can use the [Enzyme libraries's shallow renderer](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html)  for this.

```
//MyAwesomeComponent.js
import { Warning } from 'my-custom-module';
export default class MyAwesomeComponent extends Component{


    render(){
        return (<Warning>Lorem ipsum</Warning>);
    }
}


//MyAwesomeComponent.test.js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MyAwesomeComponent from './MyAwesomeComponent';

it('renders <MyAwesomeComponent />', () => {
    const shallowMyComponent = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(shallowMyComponent).toMatchSnapshot()
});
```

This should show your snapshot as Warning without going a level deeper.

Comment: I actually do a shallow render of the component under test, so unfortunately this is not the issue.

Comment: But your remark concerning "uglify" put me in the right direction. When I disable that option in Webpack (`optimization: { minimize: false }`) the modules are exported by their original name, and in the consuming project the snapshots look OK. In my case, minification is the responsibility of the consuming project, so it's no problem disabling it in the custom module.